# How do I permit date selector attributes in Rails and Formtastic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic, strong-parameters

## Latest

I have switched to Simple form. No problem with permitting date attributes there.

## Recent attempts

I have put a demo repository on Github illustrating the problem:

This one uses formtastic and displays my problem with:

```
Unpermitted parameters: date_of_receipt(1i), date_of_receipt(2i), date_of_receipt(3i), date_of_receipt(i)
```

https://github.com/bigos/permit_date_selector/commit/9f142b79c51e71dca35c988125a2912b83b91972

This one doesn't use formtastic and works fine;

https://github.com/bigos/permit_date_selector/commit/4c53b934ac5cd3f04241bf462e7b677ef5d28335

## Initial post

When I try to submit my form I get this message

```
Unpermitted parameters: date_of_receipt(i)
```

I have :date_of_receipt in the list of permitted parameters.

My form input selecting the date looks as follows:

```
<%= f.input :date_of_receipt, as: :date_select %>
```

Should I give up on formtastic and go back to standard forms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a fresh Rails app (using Rails 4.1.5 and Formtastic 2.3.1) to try to replicate, and I can't, so I'm closing. Here's what I had:

```
# Migration
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :body
      t.datetime :published_at

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

# Model
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
end

# Controller
class PostsController < ApplicationController
 def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    if @post.save
      redirect_to @post
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  protected

  def post_params
    params[:post].permit(:title, :body, :published_at)
  end
end

# View
<%= semantic_form_for @post do |f| %>
  <%= f.inputs do %>
    <%= f.input :title %>
    <%= f.input :body %>
    <%= f.input :published_at %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.actions do %>
    <%= f.action :submit %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

By simply permitting `:published_at`, I was able to successfully save a `Post` into the database with the time I had selected. Here's the development.log:

```
Started POST "/posts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-06 21:13:37 +1000
Processing by PostsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Jv4Pd7aNgvjkCtzrX+gHNeCNfX3L8t6IpEOEAWzdeIo=",     "post"=>{"title"=>"sdfgs", "body"=>"sdgfdfg", "published_at(1i)"=>"2019", "published_at(2i)"=>"1",     "published_at(3i)"=>"1", "published_at(4i)"=>"00", "published_at(5i)"=>"01"}, "commit"=>"Create Post"}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "posts" ("body", "created_at", "published_at", "title", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?,     ?, ?)  [["body", "sdgfdfg"], ["created_at", "2014-09-06 11:13:37.685160"], ["published_at", "2019-01-01 00:01:00    .000000"], ["title", "sdfgs"], ["updated_at", "2014-09-06 11:13:37.685160"]]
   (8.8ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/posts/3
Completed 302 Found in 12ms (ActiveRecord: 9.1ms)
```

There's no extra trickery required, this is how you do it :)

Answer (score 0):

When you inspect the element on the page, you will see three different elements for date_select.

`model[date_of_receipt(1i)], model[date_of_receipt(2i)], model[date_of_receipt(3i)]`

So you will have to permit

```
date_of_receipt(1i), date_of_receipt(2i), date_of_receipt(3i)
```

in your controller

Comment: It didn't work :-( . I still have Unpermitted parameters: date_of_receipt(1i), date_of_receipt(2i), date_of_receipt(3i), date_of_receipt(i)

Comment: undefined method `date_of_receipt' for #<ReceiptsController:0x007fa6b5d5a328>